# Form-level validation does not behave as expected

Tags: redux-form

Using `redux-form 7.0.3`, I'm unable to get the `Field` validate API to do anything.

First, I created a basic, minimal example templated off of [the docs](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/fieldLevelValidation/).

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

// removed validation fns
const required = value => {
  console.log('Test of validation fn')
  return (value ? undefined : 'Required')
}

// unchanged
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) =>
  <div>
    <label>
      {label}
    </label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched &&
        ((error &&
          <span>
            {error}
          </span>) ||
          (warning &&
            <span>
              {warning}
            </span>))}
    </div>
  </div>

// removed fields & made into React Component
class FieldLevelValidations extends Component {
  render(){
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="test"
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Test Component"
          validate={required}
        />
        <div>
          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldLevelValidation'
})(FieldLevelValidations)
```

From this I would assume that the forms reducer processes an action that sets a prop that can be accessed in `renderField`, but it does not. Both `error` and `warning` are undefined, and `required` is never called. Additionally, there is no `isValid` or the like property set in the store. I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm missing some critical piece, but I would expect more to be happening here. Also, some greater detail in the docs would be nice.

Comment: change your `FieldLevelValidationForm` to `FieldLevelValidations`

Comment: My bad, it is in fact the same component. Just a typo.

Comment: can't see anything wrong with your code, can you see state changed when you click the field and click somewhere else?

Comment: Yep, there are 2 actions dispatched `redux-form/FOCUS` and `redux-form/BLUR`. The final state is as follows:

    `{
      fields: {
        test: {
          touched: true
        },
       anyTouched: true
      }
    }`